# Ну когда же пофиксят оформление кода на мете?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн, нытьё

Давно уже пора, я давно даже на metaSO видел соответствующую тему со скриншотом и описанием, что надо исправить. Но почему-то никто не правит.

> ```
> Блок кода в цитате
> до сих пор
> показывается как inline-код
> ```

Comment: Вообще не понятно что было и стало.

Comment: @älёxölüt, было примерно так: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK1nz.png (только расстояний между строками вроде не было), а стало как сейчас в вопросе: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1slIb.png

Comment: [Оно?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295584/339911)

Comment: @älёxölüt, да, оно, но многострочная версия :)

Comment: Англострочная!!!

Comment: @älёxölüt, пофиксили за 3 года :)

Comment: классика прямо.

Comment: @älёxölüt, на нашей мете вроде тоже вопрос был - не помнишь?